# Visualización paralela entre Visual Studio Code y la página Web

Tags: visual-studio

Desde Visual Studio Code se puede ver al tiempo que se programa cómo quedaría en la WEB? como en una segunda pantalla? Necesito seleccionar código y que se vea exactamente donde se proyecta en lo que sería la Web.